# Is there any way to make it so that a cell can only be changed once in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Sheet which I would like to use as a simultaneous sign up for many people for timeslots for an event. We have noticed that what can happen is users erasing each other's entries in the sheet. Ideally we would like to make it so once someones name is entered for a timeslot it cannot be removed by other users.

I've tried to use data validation to reject certain criteria, but I've only managed to get it to reject a cell changing from blank to a non-blank value. Which I achieved with the following:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4df1.png). But I'd like the opposite behaviour, with some additional functionality

Changing the formula to NOT(ISBLANK(B2)) doesn't seem to put any restriction on the cell at all as hitting backspace or delete on cell seems to clear the contents without ever considering that an input to check. Changing the value never causes the cell to go blank so it doesn't seem to affect changing either. I'm really at a loss as to how to do this and any help is appreciated. I'm open to solutions which use VBA or other programming languages to get the desired result as well.

Comment: Don't give users direct access to other users data.  In other words do all of your user entry in webapps or dialogs

Comment: How would I go about implementing a dialog within Google Sheets? Or would I need to look for a different app?

Comment: [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)

Comment: A simple alternative would be to collect entries through a Google Form, add another sheet to the document with responses where only the first entry (by timestamp) for a time slot would be displayed, and make this sheet view only to users.